# The distribution of an event whose waiting time is exactly k

Tags: probability, expected-value, exponential-distribution

I am trying to solve the following problem

Assume busses arrive with the interval exactly 10 min one after another. At the end of a working day, I take a bus home. Let α be my expected waiting time for the train. Find α.

So, my approach here is as follows, first I need to model the following distribution, then integrate the PDF of the corresponding distribution to find the expected value. The problem is, I am not sure whether the distribution is Exponential with lambda 1/10. I am given the waiting time between two successive events, but it is not the average waiting time, and that confuses me.
Can you help me understand the distribution??

Comment: Is there a chance that the train may crash into the bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem is in modelling, so let me propose two models:

1. Buses arrive every 10 minutes all day, starting at midnight 0:00. I finish my work somewhere between 5:00 and 5:10 pm and I wish to take the first bus. Let's say the time I finish work is uniformly distributed.
2. I finish my work at 5:00 pm sharp. Buses arrive every 10 minutes, but their starting time is random. Let's say the first bus arrives somewhere between 6:00 and 7:00 am, and again with uniform distribution.

In all possible models, my waiting time $X$ is a random variable with values in $[0,10]$ (measured in minutes). In both cases above, $X$ is actually uniformly distributed, which gives us the estimates time of $5$ minutes.

---

The modelling part is not strictly mathematical. The author of the problem probably wants you to assume (or realize, in part) that the waiting time is uniformly distributed in $[0,10]$. However, one can come up with different models:

3. The first bus is at midnight 0:00 and I always finish work at 5:03, in which case I always wait 7 minutes.
4. I always finish at 5:00 and the first bus arrives between 6:00 and 6:58 (with uniform distribution), in which case the estimated time is slightly smaller than 5 minutes.
5. I'm taking a bus, but I'm actually waiting for a train, so I missed my chance entirely.

Comment: Yeah, I, actually, thought about uniform distribution, now after explanation, it is clear.

Comment: Hopefully this is meant to be a modeling problem, in which students are meant to make reasonable assumptions that they make sure to state. It seems to me like sometimes these are actually questions in a probability class, and the students are led to believe that, e.g. the expected waiting time **is** 5 minutes, rather than - in my model, in which I am assuming that these two times are independent and uniformly distributed, the expected waiting time is 5 minutes.

Comment: Yes, I hope so. At some point students need to see the distinction between the reality and the mathematical model in hand, like in [Bertrand paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)), for example. But even if this pops up as a problem in probability class, there's still some room for discussion, I guess. It would be worse if it appeared as a test problem.